# "Воды" in the expression "мне хочется воды"

Tags: грамматика, словоупотребление

Some textbooks on Russian grammar say that the partitive genitive of a noun appears only as the object of a verb, never as the subject.  It appears to me that *воды* in the above expression would be the subject. If so, it should be replaced by *вода* grammatically. But *воды* seems more frequently used. Why?

Answer (score 8):

In the phrase *мне хочется воды*, grammatically, there is a zero subject, one verb and two objects.

It's an impersonal phrase, which is similar to English impersonal constructs like "it seems to me", "it occurs to me" etc, except that phrases like that have a zero subject in Russian (as opposed to English, which has an actual subject, "it").

So grammatically, both *мне* and *воды* are objects to *хочется*.

Note that object, subject and verb are purely grammatical terms, which are not to be confused with thematic roles of agent, patient and instrument.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I understand that the _воды_ is one of the objects in this sentence. On the other hand, I have learned that the accusative does not appear as the object of a reflexive verb. If so and if the case where the object is _такая кукла_, instead of _вода_, what can you say other than "мне хочется такую куклу"?

Comment: @okazatsky "Я хочу такую куклу" i.e. non-reflexive form. But I should note sometimes people _do_ use reflexive+accusative. It's not a good habit but could be tolerable in a spoken language.

Comment: @okazatsky: it's not accusative, it's genitive. You can only use partitive genitive with uncountable nouns. But could you please cite the excerpt from the textbook about no accusative with reflexive verbs? *Бояться, слушаться* etc. do accept animate objects in accusative.

Comment: @Quassnoi: Thank you so much for your comment. One of my textbooks says (in Japanese) that verbs with -ся do not take any objects in accusative. After reading your comment, I found a report, which says that there are nine reflexive verbs accepting objects in accusative and that _хотеться_, one of them, takes an object in animate accusative or in inanimate genitive, in agreement with your comment.  However, some main dictionaries show the phrase "дочке давно хочется такую куклу" as an example, even though _кукла_ is inanimate. I am still confused.

Comment: @okazatsky: *кукла* can be both animate and inanimate (both *взять свои куклы* and *взять своих кукол* are valid), and it is animate in *хочется куклу*. With this very verb (*хотеться*), you can use inanimate uncountable objects in genitive or animate objects in accusative. The latter is grammatically acceptable but considered bad style, as user4419802 above mentioned.

Comment: @Quassnoi , Вы утверждаете, что **"мне хочется такую куклу"**  it's not accusative, it's genitive? Просклоняйте, пожалуйста, словосочетание `такая кукла` по русским падежам.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24280/discussion-between-quassnoi-and-avtokod).

Answer (score 2):

The phrase `мне хочется воды` doesn't contain any subject. It's an impersonal sentence where `мне` and `воды` are objects. Therefore, the rule you mentioned isn't broken in the sentence.

Regarding the sentence, there's no direct analog of such construction in English. You may consider `мне хочется` as a synonym of `я хочу`.

Answer (score 0):

**`Мне хочется воды`** is exactly `*I am in a state of*`  thirstyness, a physiological state (that implies a psychological) corresponding to a strong need of water".

Right from the English phrase we can see why there is genetive, because "of smth" has direct corresponding with Russian Gen.

The `хочется` is very special verb. It sets a person in a certain complex state in virtue of his perceiving.

```
мне чудится сон                  Nom
мне делается операция            Nom
мне хочется танцев                  Gen
мне видится образ                Nom
мне хочется моря, песка, солнца     Gen
мне слышится песня               Nom
```

In a certain sense in `мне хочется воды` there *is* a subject, a psychological state only I know I am in. This subject you may consider (in English, like weather verbs) as included, "It's needing; (my state of the need of ...)", where in the place of "need" can be placed smth with [25+ meanings in English](http://translate.academic.ru/%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C/ru/en/).

`Я хочу воды` vs `мне хочется воды` is an inappropriate analogous. When we say `Я хочу ...` we mean, first, "I am needing smth", but `мне хочется ...` is "I am feeling ... (state of “being” in the present)" and "I am aware of this state".

`Я хочу` is an analogous `Я делаю`. Thus in `мне делается операция` the noun `операция` is a word in Nominative, and there is huge number of examples with such verbs. It's something that we consciously try to do, whereas a psychological state is something else.

---

[As you say](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/8805/%d0%92%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b-in-the-expression-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8b#comment19581_8807),

> there are ... reflexive verbs accepting objects in accusative and that
>   `хотеться`, one of them, takes an object in animate accusative or in
>   inanimate genitive.

There is more examples `хотеться_praes + N_accu` without the connection with in/animate, so it is fully literate.  [Proof](https://www.google.com.ua/search?num=30&hl=ru&tbm=bks&q=%22%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E%22&oq=%22%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%8E%22)

It would be interesting to show that there are `хотеться_praes + Noun_instr`. Examples with a context [the first](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=uVonAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC%22&dq=%22%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BC%22) , [the second](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D1%81+%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BC+%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE+%E2%80%95+%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5.+%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0+%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D0%B4%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83.&num=20&safe=off&tbm=bks&oq=%D1%81+%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BC+%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE+%E2%80%95+%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5.+%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B0+%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC+%D0%BF%D0%BE+%D0%B4%D1%8B%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%83.)